# Как правильно обновить данные в таблице

Tags: yii2

Пишу круд форму для возможности обновления записей или внесения новых в таблицу и возник вопрос - а как правильно это делается. Раньше бы я просто через js собрал бы данные формы и аяксом бы отправил запрос на какую-нибудь страницу, где она бы обновила\внесла изменения в таблицу, но есть ощущение, что этот подход не правильный. Посоветуйте, как в и yii2 этот функционал правильно реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

можно использовать PJax и GridView
пример: https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/772/pjax-on-activeform-and-gridview-yii2
чуть подробнее: https://p0vidl0.info/yii2-primeryaem-pjax-na-activeform-i-gridview.html